# Spring Boot application giving message No message found for locale 'en_GB'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, message, properties-file

In my Spring Boot application I am getting the message: `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'invalidAdminPassword' for locale 'en_GB'.`

I know this is due to the `MessageSource` object which in my code is defined as:

```
@Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
        messageSource.setBasename("messages_en_GB");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); // Refresh cache once per hour.
        return messageSource;
    }
```

In `messages_en_GB.properties`, I have message:

```
# Other validation messages.
invalidAdminPassword=Invalid password.
```

And in the controller concerned I have:

```
System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("invalidAdminPassword", null, Locale.UK));
```

Just to test the retrieval from the `messages_en_GB.properties` file.

I believe that I am using Spring Boot default settings so why do I get the message `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'invalidAdminPassword' for locale 'en_GB'.`?

Can anyone advise?

Comment: The message is about the key 'name.required'. It has nothing to do with the key 'invalidAdminPassword'. Reading the message helps. Reading the stack trace of the exception also helps.

Comment: I have corrected this in the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you have both a 'messages.properties' and a 'massages_en_GB.properties' you do not need to refer the localized basename. Just a plain setBasename("messages") will do. (Nice example can be found here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: there is a minimal running example in the [link](https://github.com/tillmannheigel/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSourceExample).

To solve your problem, please answer, please give some more details:

a) Where have you put your messages.properties?

b) Are there more than one messages{.*}.properties?

Comment: a. File `message_en_GB.properties` is in folder `src/main/resources`. b. There is only one messages file.

Comment: nice to hear. What was the actual problem?

Comment: I was getting the `LOCALE` settings for `en_GB` and `UK` mixed up. In the end I simply used `US` as per your demonstration on GitHub.

Comment: Only filename is not working for me d'ont know why?But we solved this issue by adding the classpath:filename in basename .And Its works fine and i can add n number of property files in my configuration etc.   messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages1","classpath:messages2");

Answer (score 1):

There are the possible errors that can be checked.

1. If message source files are in defined place.
2. Is there any message source file for the requested locale.
3. Do have defined a bean named "messageSource".

If using java config, it must be like

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
     messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages");
}
```

Here our message file should be inside WEB-INF as defined.

or

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
public MessageSource setUpmessageSource() {}
```

If we define only

```
public MessageSource setUpmessageSource() {}
```

then there is no bean named `messageSource`